# Can I use backend api's without running the project?

Tags: java, spring, reactjs

I'm currently working in the frontend of an app and to test my code while using an api from backend I need to run everytime the project to access the data from de DB; is it possible to use the api's without opening the ide and running the backend everytime?

Comment: Do you mean "how can I make API calls without the backend"? (Do you still need access to the database? -- Your wording is a bit confusing.) If you just want to test standalone API calls you can use an application like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) (which is made just for API testing), or you can write a smaller test API script that doesn't run your whole backend.

Comment: do you have the option to do something from a terminal window like mvn spring-boot:run and leave the back end running?

Comment: You could use a tool like Pact ( https://docs.pact.io ) that can mock out your backend.   Its main use is that it can also substitute for your front end, and is therefore a testing tool to confirm consistency between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Without opening an ide and making the server to up, you will not be able to access the api hence you cant. But there is a way to achieve it try mocking the api/DB data and keep it in local.

Example: back-end api - "api/get/users" returns {"id": 1, "name": "xyz"}

You can copy the response and paste in one JSON/JS file lets say, mocks//users.json also has {"id": 1, "name": "xyz"}

And refer this mock from your code, by this way you can get the response faster(as its local file referred) and you can easily switch to backend api when ever you need to ensure your flow.

Let me know if you need any other details

Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

There are only two choices, run the backend, or mock the backend. [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) comes to mind for a very quick REST API. The other thing which I do is instead of running the backend locally, is if you have a development build deployed, you can run your front-end against that, by making use of environment variables. For instance my `.env` file looks like this because we are using AWS API gateway:

```
# LOCAL
REACT_APP_API=/api

# DEV
# REACT_APP_API=https://todo.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/todo
```

In my code I use `process.env.REACT_APP_API` to make REST calls. When I want to use the `DEV` environment I swap `REACT_APP_API`.

Note: You need to make sure your CORS policy allows this and any other bits of your application which might not like this. Such as for my case we use Cognito, so I had to add `http://localhost:3000` as an allowable redirect URI, that might not be applicable for you but hopefully you get the point.

Also it is considered bad practice to use the .env file which is committed into your repo as a means of managing environment variables, I only use this file for development purposes, come deploy time, all my `REACT_APP_..` variables are taken from a proper environment management tool.

Comment: You could also mock at the `Javascript` level but IMO this is very difficult to maintain, and very disconnected because you don't then make HTTP calls to a backend, so you don't have the latency and network behavior you otherwise would.